# How to convert an array into a list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I need to change the following array in a list whitin dictionary.

```
>>> g = {'x': time,}    
{'x': array([ 0.        ,  0.08333333,  0.16666667,  0.25      ,  0.33333333,
        0.41666667,  0.5       ,  0.58333333,  0.66666667,  0.75      ,
        0.83333333,  0.91666667,  1.        ])}
```

I need remove 'array'to look like this:

```
{'x': [ 0.        ,  0.08333333,  0.16666667,  0.25      ,  0.33333333,
    0.41666667,  0.5       ,  0.58333333,  0.66666667,  0.75      ,
    0.83333333,  0.91666667,  1.        ]}
```

only python list without array

any idea?

Comment: `g['x'] = list(g['x'])` ?

Comment: If the comment from @Iguananaut is not the answer you seek, can you please rephrase your question? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: or I think `g = { 'x': list(time), }`

Comment: If it helps your understanding at all, there's nothing special about any object being a value in a `dict`.  All the object knows is that it's an array.  It doesn't know it's an item in `dict`.  It may be an item in many dicts (in fact it probably is), lists, or any other ways of referencing an object in Python.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code,

```
key_value = g['x']  #g is the dictionary
g['x'] = list(key_value) #key_value is x
print g
```